# How can I change the colour of whitespace indicators in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code supports whitespace indicators, which it makes configurable via its `editor.renderWhitespace` setting. How can I change the colour of the whitespace indicators?

Comment: meta note: this question is posted for https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/13in0gu/help_me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `editorWhitespace.foreground` [colour customization](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) point.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#ff0000"
},
```

If you want to configure the colour on a per-theme basis, then wrap the customization in a `"[theme name]": { ... }` block.